# PHP Rewrite fsockopen to curl conversion

Tags: php, curl

This is a function I have for grabbing a game server ip and returning the name. The web host I am on does not support this method so I want to have it completely converted to curl to try. Any ideas?

```
$ip = $serverip;
queryport = 29416;

$socket = @fsockopen("udp://".$ip, $queryport , $errno, $errstr, 1);

stream_set_timeout($socket, 1);
stream_set_blocking($socket, TRUE);
fwrite($socket, "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x54Source Engine Query\x00");
$response = fread($socket, 4096);
@fclose($socket);

$packet = explode("\x00", substr($response, 6), 5);
$server = array();

$server['name'] = $packet[0];
$servername = ( $server['name'] );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Initially you are assigning $serverip to $ip; check whether you are getting correct value or not. Else you can use below curl code to get the ip address.

```
$url = 'http://gmail.com';
$wrapper = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $wrapper);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$ips = get_curl_ips($wrapper);
fclose($wrapper);
echo end($ips);
function get_curl_ips($fp){ rewind($fp);
$str = fread($fp, 8192);
$regex = '/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches)) { return array_unique($matches[0]); }
else { return false; } }
```

Comment: `$serverip` would always be correct, it comes straight from the API's array, and if printed out works fine alone. I need a way to take that IP and then fetch the server name string to return it. Which the code I provided works no doubt - just my web host won't support it so I need a cURL method.